# Simple Qt Quick example isn't drawn in android emulator

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-emulator, qtquick2

By default then creating new Qt Quick 1.3 project it creates stub with 3 buttons and menu. It works fine on my smartphone but in emulator (tried standard one and genymotion, armv7 and x86) it doesn't draw anything. Only white screen. But if I "touch" (click) there buttons are supposed to be it reacts with a pop up as it should. Some part of error log in console at the moment: http://pastebin.com/1e7ZiGKq

I don't get what is wrong and because I haven't found any mentions of this or threads I think it's some sort of the bug/misconfiguration it should work correctly. How to solve this problem?
P.S. Normal QWidget app works fine.

Comment: where you able to solve this issue? I'm using Qt 5.7 :(

Comment: @cessmestreet unfortunately no. I've created a bug report https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44697 and it seems that there other people with same issue (it was even confirmed by commercial customers, it seems), but it has low priority status. You can vote it up and leave your comments there.

In my case, I used few workarounds - I tested on my laptop with iGPU, where it worked fine. I compiled it for desktop to test the functionality (qt is cross-platform, after all) and I tested on the real HW.